# Is there any replacement content element for "Sitemaps of selected pages" in typo3 headless installation?

Tags: typo3

We have installed Typo3 11.5.21 with the headless extension. But whenever we are adding the content element **Sitemaps of selected pages** the page is showing the Typo3 Exception error. Can anyone please let me know if there is any alternative content element? The content element is working fine on Typo3 version 10.4 without headless.

[image]

Comment: So what is the exception you get?

Comment: Added the screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

You could change the if clause at line 138 in EXT:headless/Classes/ContentObject/JsonContentContentObject.php

from:

```
if ($this->isColPolsGroupingEnabled($conf) && $element->colPos >= 0) {
    $data['colPos' . $element->colPos][] = $element;
```

to:

```
if ($this->isColPolsGroupingEnabled($conf) && $element['colPos'] >= 0) {
    $data['colPos' . $element['colPos']][] = $element;
```

If that works it seems to be a bug in the EXT:headless. Then you should report an issue to the headless bugtracker and ask for an condition when accessing `$element`.

Until it's fixed you could either hardcode the fix in the EXT:headless code. But thats not pretty clean.

Better create a patchfile and patch the extension while doing composer update (Assumes you run TYPO3 in composer mode).